# Display HTML from textbox in a iFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here's what I have for now :

http://jsfiddle.net/QSDTV/1/

Is there a way I can type HTML code (including the  tag, and  tag, and so on> in the textarea and that when I click on the "Update content" button at the bottom, it renders my html code in that iFrame? Or maybe it should be displayed in a DIV? I don't know.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

try this with this code.

http://jsfiddle.net/QSDTV/2/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#update").click(function() {
      $("#content").html($("#editor").val()) 
    }) 
})
```

Comment: Thank you! Almost there...The thing is I need the HTML render to be in a fixed size DIV. Also, I have tried using <h1> tag, and it's not working.